# MathJax rendering on multiple lines instead of inline

Tags: flask, mathjax

I'm baffled - simple, standard MathJax was working on my Flask app but has stopped working. I am not sure when it happened and have not been able to isolate the cause. My MathJax script is directly from the website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS
MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]} 
  });
</script>
```

The view route looks anything like this:

```
@bp.route('/history')
@login_required
def history():
   papers = Paper.query.all()
   return render_template('main/history.html', papers=papers)
```

The HTML/Jinja looks akin to this:

```
{% for paper in papers %}
<div class='paper'>


{% if showsub %}
  {{ paper.subber.firstname }}
  {% if paper.volunteer.firstname is defined %}
  &#8594;&nbsp;{{ paper.volunteer.firstname }}
  {% endif %}<br>
  {% endif %}
  <span class='title'>{{ paper.title }}</span><br>
  {{ paper.authors }}<br>
  <a href='{{ paper.link }}'>{{ paper.link }}</a><br>
  {{ paper.abstract }}<br>
  {% if showsub %}{% if paper.comment %}{% set comment = 
    paper.comment.split('\n') %}
  <span class='comment'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Comments:</span>{% 
    for i in comment  %}{{ i }}<br>{% endfor %}</span>
  {% endif %}{% endif %}
  {% if showvote %}
  <span class='votes'>{{ paper.score_n }}/{{ paper.score_d }} votes.
  </span>
  {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I am not currently using any other CSS or javascript. When the code renders on the page, some of it looks okay, but a lot of it ends up hanging over multiple lines. I can't figure out what's going on here, haven't been able to find other reports of similar behavior. Any ideas?

[screenshot of the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akoF2.png)

Comment: Just a note: cdn.mathjax.org was shut down years ago and does not contain the latest version https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I looked at the source code and realized the MathJax scripts were showing up with double backslashes while MathJax needed them to be single backslashes. I'm not exactly sure whether the problem happens when I scrape the MathJax scripts or whether I could configure MathJax to interpret the double backslashes correctly, but I'm using Jinja to replace the double backslashes with a single backslash when it renders the page, and that seems to be working. Clunky, but it works.

```
{{ paper.abstract|replace('\\\\', '\\') }}<br>
```